# discord.py @bot.command() not running

Tags: python, function, bots, discord.py

I've got something like this.

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get
import requests
from Moderator.badwords import words
import time
import datetime
from Stats.uptime import data

help_command = commands.DefaultHelpCommand(
    no_category = 'Commands'
)

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="Hey there, I'm Botty (for example)!", help_command=help_command, intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention + " hello!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Ready!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in words:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Oops! Seems like " + message.author.mention + " was trying to send a message that was breaking the " + bot.get_channel(783064049859559434).mention + ". Luckily, I deleted it before it caused any more damage. Don't send any more messages like that!\n\nIf you think that I made an error, please report it in " + bot.get_channel(783074030265040916).mention + ", " + bot.get_channel(783074002255478848).mention + " or in " + bot.get_channel(783092164590174251).mention)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  print(f"{member} joined the server")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Now, I can compile and run this code with no errors, and when a member joins or a user sends a message, all works perfectly fine. But when it comes to run commands, it does not even start. Is there something i'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are initializing the bot with something along the lines of `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')`?

Comment: ill post all the code

Comment: @thshea but yes, it's initialized

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The documentation:](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

> Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your on_message.

If you override an `on_message`, you need to use `await bot.process_commands(message)` so that the commands are processed. Try adding that to your `on_message` event.

Comment: Yess! Now it works. Please add the `await` because it's missing so others don't get confussed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this code is perfectly fine, did you define the prefix correctly?
To define the prefix you need to import `commands` from `discord.ext`
Your bot should look like this:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
TOKEN = ...
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
#####
async functions
#####
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: It was already defined although it wasn't in the code posted. The code worked perfectly fine before today.