# Suggest command not working in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently coding a bot in discord.py that does mod commands like kick, etc. I'm trying to make a command that you can suggest something to the server like they make a channel called suggestion-channel, when they do the command it sends it to that channel. I have a command that sends a message to a specific channel for bot suggestions, but that's the closest I've gotten. below is the code that I have for the suggest command in cogs, yes I use command handling.

```
@commands.command()
async def suggest(self ,ctx , *, suggestion):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Suggestion from {ctx.author.name}", description=suggestion, color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Suggestion created by {ctx.author}")
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.server.channels, name="suggestion-channel")
    message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
    await message.add_reaction("❌")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send("Thank you for your suggestion!")
```

Comment: hi, interesting, was there an error?

Comment: no errors, it doesn't send anything

Comment: I’m a bit confused about what you’re trying to figure out. Is the current code not working somehow, are you trying to figure out what to do next? Please elaborate.

Comment: @StarbuckBarista im trying to make a command where you type 'm.suggest [message]'. it will then send the suggestion to another channel in there server with the suggestion so the mods can read it and make the fix in the server. I hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, so is the command just not calling?

Comment: yes, no errors and its not sending anything back when the command is done.

Comment: you could at least use `print()` to see which line of code is execute and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`.

Comment: you could create minimal working code with your problem - and then we can copy it, run it  and test ideas. You use `cog` so we should see how you use it. Maybe problem is in different place.

Comment: ok so if i delete `channel = discord.utils.get(message.server.channels, name="suggestion-channel")` the command works but with it, it doesn't not

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run it in console/terminal? In `discord.utils.get()` you use `message` which you get in next line `message = ...` so you have it in wrong order. First `message = ...`, next `discord.utils.get(message, ...)` OR maybe you should use `ctx` or `ctx.message` instead of `message` in `discord.utils.get(...)`

Comment: no, no errors pop up in the console and I'm using error handling so like the command not found stuff. Nothing pops up. also, your saying to switch things up like `server.channels.message`? not sure what your saying.

Comment: in `discord.utils.get(...)` you use variable `message` which doesn't exist. Maybe it should be `discord.utils.get(ctx.server.channels, ...)` or `discord.utils.get( ctx.message.server.channels, ...)`. I can't test it.

Comment: no, none of them work

Comment: Use `ctx.guild` instead of `ctx.server`, which is deprecated in newer versions of discord.py. Other than that, you should be able to send the message to your suggestion-channel successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not getting the channel in an `on_message` event, or using a user's message to get the server's channels. You'll have to replace `message` with `ctx`. Secondly, `ctx.server` is no longer valid since discord.py's migration. It would now be known as [`ctx.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild), which you can read about in their docs.

```py
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.server.channels, name="suggestion-channel")
    # change this to:
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="suggestion-channel")
```

[image: Changing the code working]

Otherwise, if you find that any of your other commands are not working, you may have not processed your `on_message` event. You can view questions on how to solve this:

- [Why does on_message stop commands from working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331096/why-does-on-message-stop-commands-from-working)
- [await process_commands(message)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) [docs]
- [discord.py @bot.command() not running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208333/14420546)

Comment: @JustPhantom50 If my answer answered your question, don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer by using the _green_ tick under the upvote and downvote of this answer.