# Coinflip command on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i was creating a head or tails command for my discord.py bot, when i debug the file, the terminal doesn't give me problems, the bot appears online but when i type the command, the bot doesn't respond.
Here's the code:

```
@client.command()
async def coinflip(ctx, responses):
responses = ['testa','croce']
message = await ctx.send(":coin: sto lanciando la moneta...")
await message.edit(content=f":coin: è uscito **{random.choice(responses)}**")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py @bot.command() not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207823/discord-py-bot-command-not-running)

Comment: If the user doesn't give the bot any input you should remove ```responses``` from the function/command.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for that.

- Make sure that the bot has permission to read messages and send messages for that channel.
- If you use an on_message() event, you need to add `await bot.process_commands(message)` to that event.

```py
async def on_message(message):
    # Your code here
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```